# why i can't dispatch_release when dealloc object?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, release

Use gcd, do some async homework.
When dealloc did call, at this line "**dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{})**", it was aways life in thread.

here is example of code (use ARC).

ThingWithAQueue:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc in Thing");
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{});//check the queue is safe
    dispatch_release(_queue);
    _queue = nil;
    NSLog(@"Dealloc in Thing, done");
}

- (void)will{
    NSLog(@"will test gcd ");
}

- (void)did{
    NSLog(@"did test gcd ");
}

- (void)addSomeWork1:(void(^)(void))work
{

    if (!_queue)
        _queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.johsrl.ThingQueue", NULL);


    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        [self will];
        work();
        //Since I refer to self here, dealloc will not be run until after all blocks complete
        [self did];
        NSLog(@"Work is done: %@",self);
    });

}
```

ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)test1:(id)sender {

    ThingWithAQueue *thing = [[ThingWithAQueue alloc] init];

    [thing addSomeWork1:^{sleep(1);}];
    [thing addSomeWork1:^{sleep(1);}];
    [thing addSomeWork1:^{sleep(1);}];
    [thing addSomeWork1:^{sleep(1);}];
    [thing addSomeWork1:^{sleep(1);}];

    NSLog(@"The view controller is done with test 1.");

}
```

log:

```
2015-04-06 14:47:17.200 GCD[18524:3570041] The view controller is done with test 1.
2015-04-06 14:47:17.200 GCD[18524:3570124] do will test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:18.206 GCD[18524:3570124] do did test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:18.206 GCD[18524:3570124] Work is done: <ThingWithAQueue: 0x7b246660>
2015-04-06 14:47:18.207 GCD[18524:3570124] do will test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:19.208 GCD[18524:3570124] do did test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:19.209 GCD[18524:3570124] Work is done: <ThingWithAQueue: 0x7b246660>
2015-04-06 14:47:19.209 GCD[18524:3570124] do will test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:20.209 GCD[18524:3570124] do did test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:20.210 GCD[18524:3570124] Work is done: <ThingWithAQueue: 0x7b246660>
2015-04-06 14:47:20.210 GCD[18524:3570124] do will test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:21.212 GCD[18524:3570124] do did test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:21.212 GCD[18524:3570124] Work is done: <ThingWithAQueue: 0x7b246660>
2015-04-06 14:47:21.212 GCD[18524:3570124] do will test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:22.216 GCD[18524:3570124] do did test gcd 
2015-04-06 14:47:22.216 GCD[18524:3570124] Work is done: <ThingWithAQueue: 0x7b246660>
2015-04-06 14:47:22.216 GCD[18524:3570124] Dealloc in Thing
```

When i click "pause program exeuction" button on Xcode.
the show:

[image]

if i remove the line "**dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{});**"

or

remove about self methods in GCD block (  **[self did];** &   **[self did];** ),

the code is ok.

what's happen in **dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{});** on this thread queue.

"dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{});" is a right way for check the queue is thread ?

Comment: You question is unclear. Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve and what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: "dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{});" is a right way for check the queue is thread ?

Comment: If you are using ARC there is no need to use dispatch_release() and hence no need to check if queue is safe to release.

Comment: What's about MRC in GCD? thanks`

Comment: Even if you are using MRC any call to dispatch_async will retain queue until the block finishes. So I think even if you release the queue it will still be in memory till all of the blocks submitted to it finishes.